# Exception in remote debugging for SpringBoot Application

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a SpringBoot Application which internally communicate with the JMS and activeMQ. I have a .cmd file to start that application. I have added arguments to enable remote debugging, so I can debug the application in eclipse. The cmd file as below:

```
set JAVA_CP=./;./config;./lib/*
set JAVA_JMX=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=10090 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
set JAVA_CL=com.myapp.test.server.TestServer
set JAVA_OP=-Xmx280m -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=8090,suspend=n %JAVA_JMX%
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" %JAVA_OP% -cp "%JAVA_CP%" %JAVA_CL%
```

Now when I start ActiveMQ and then my application with above .cmd file. I got following error:

```
18:27:53.234 [main] ERROR [o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol] Failed to start end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
```

If I remove the debugging arguments(`-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=8090,suspend=n`) from .cmd file, it works fine.

I search about this and found that it may possible that two instances are running, but I verified that also. Can you please help?

Comment: Do you have something else listening on 8090? Your app maybe? Try different port

Comment: Maybe the port 8090 is already being used. Have you tried changing it to another port?

Comment: I think the app port is 8090 and debug port is 4000. `-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=4000 "`

Comment: I have tried with different port, also with debug port as 4000. but it's still not working